# Akka and Java 8 TestKit by Example

Tags: unit-testing, java-8, akka, akka-testkit

Java 8 and Akka 2.12:2.5.16 here. I am trying to write my first (ever) Akka unit test leveraging [Akka TestKit](https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/akka-quickstart-java/testing-actors.html) and am struggling to apply the principles I see in the (very few) examples I've been able to find online.

My actors:

```
public class Child extends AbstractActor {
    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
            .match(Init.class, init -> {
                int workUnit = workService.doSomeWork();
                log.info("Performed work on {}", workUnit);
            }).build();
    }
}

public class Master extends AbstractActor {
    @Inject @Named("CHILD")
    private ActorRef child;

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
            .match(Init.class, init -> {
                child.tell(init, self());
            }).build();
    }
}
```

Very, very simple. So now I just want to write a unit tests that verifies that when the `Master` actor receives an `Init` message, that it forwards that message onto its `Child` actor. My best attempt thus far:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MasterTest {
    private ActorSystem actorSystem;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("test-system");
    }

    @After
    public void teardown() {
        Duration duration = Duration.create(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        TestKit.shutdownActorSystem(actorSystem, duration, true);
        actorSystem = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void onInit_shouldSendFordwardToChild() {
        // Given
        TestKit testKit = new TestKit(actorSystem);
        ActorRef master = actorSystem.actorOf(Props.create(Master.class, testKit));

        // When
        master.tell(new Init(), ActorRef.noSender());

        // Then
        testKit.expectMsg(Init.class);
    }
}
```

When I run this I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no matching constructor found on class com.me.myapp.Master for arguments [class akka.testkit.TestKit]
```

Can someone please help me wire the `TestKit` instance into my `Master` actor, and also help me figure out how to refactor `MasterTest` such that it verifies what I'm trying to accomplish? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, can't believe how difficult it was to get this to work :-/

In `application.conf`:

```
MyAkkApp {
  akka {
    remote {
      enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
      netty.tcp {
        hostname = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 2553
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MasterTest extends TestKit {
    static ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("MyAkkaApp",
        ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("MyAkkaApp"));

    static TestProbe child;  // The mock child
    static ActorRef master;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        child = new TestProbe(actorSystem, "Child");
        master = actorSystem.actorOf(Props.create(new Creator<Actor>() {
            @Override
            public Actor create() throws Exception {
                return new Master(child.ref());
            }
        }));
    }

    public MasterTest() {
        super(actorSystem);
    }

    @Test
    public void onInit_shouldSendFordwardToChild() {
        // Given
        Init init = new Init();

        // When
        master.tell(init, super.testActor());

        // Then
        child.expectMsg(init);  // Child should have received it
        expectNoMessage();  // Master should not be returning to sender
    }
}
```

Come on Akka folks! Support yields adoption, adoption leads to standardization, standardization means you get to sell 6-figure corporate support licenses.

Comment: I'm not sure why you had to make any changes to the transport configuration; I can't see any remoting going on. Beyond that, what's the issue? Akka doesn't do dependency injection; when I've had parent-child actors I've literally created the child from the parent (getContext().actorOf(...)), and for testing I isolate that in its own method, subclass the actor under test, and return a test probe.

Comment: Thanks @RobCrawford I'd **love** to see a sample of one of your Akka TestKit unit tests...